# typeorm shows me this error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, ts-node

I am new at typeorm and I created a user entity like this:
User.ts:

```
import {DefaultBaseEntity} from "../defaults/DefaultBaseEntity";
import {Entity, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity("users")
export class User extends DefaultBaseEntity {
    @Column()
    username: string;
    
    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    account_type: string;

    @Column()
    photo_url: string;

    @Column()
    discipline: string;

    @Column()
    class: string;

    @Column()
    confirmed: number;

}
```

and this is DefaultBaseEntity.ts

```
import { BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";

export declare class DefaultBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column()
    createdAt: Date;

    @Column()
    updatedAt: Date;
    
    constructor();
}
```

when I run the app it returns me this error: `TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined` for running the app I use ts-node. What I missed?